# Can I create an event that triggers when the input text is deleted?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input (type=text) and a select tag that I only want to display when any text is typed in the input, but remove it if the text is deleted.

There is no issue in adding the class to display the element, but when the text is removed from the input, the "else" statement is not working to remove the class.

HTML:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="input" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group hiddenInput">
        <select class="form-control" id="select">
          <option hidden disabled selected value> </option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(input){
  if(input) {
    document.getElementById('select').classList.add('show');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('select').classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.hiddenInput {
  display: none;
}

.hiddenInput.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an `else if` block instead and checking for empty input on input?

Comment: `if(input)` is not what you are thinking...

Comment: You need to check if the input (Value) text is empty. There you check the event object if is empty, and never will be.

Comment: I have tried with else if (!input) / else if (!input.value) and else if (input.value === '') but it's not working and I think I'm missing something else.

Comment: And what do you think `input` is, in context?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c7w2jdqv/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` argument isn’t the input the user is entering into the text box, it is the `event` object which contains information about the event which occurred. To get the text from the text box , you can use `this.value`. If you apply the `trim()` method to it, you can remove any white space surrounding the text, allowing you to get an empty string if the end user only enters spaces into the input box.

Also, the `keyup` event only fires your function whenever the user lets go of the key they’re pressing. For more instantaneous responses, you can use the `input` event which will trigger whenever the end user changes the text within the text box.

To check if the text box is empty you can check the input's length, if it is `0` then there is no text within the textbox and so you can hide the class. You also need to change your CSS styles to target the correct class, see example below:

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  if (this.value.trim().length) {
    document.getElementById('select').classList.add('show');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('select').classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```css
.hiddenInput .select-input {
  display: none;
}

.hiddenInput .select-input.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="input" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group hiddenInput">
  <select class="form-control select-input" id="select">
    <option hidden disabled selected value></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and solution. It worked like I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

`keyup` is not really the event you want here, and the value passed by the `keyup` event isn't the current value of the input field, it's the key event that tells you (along with many other details) which key was released.

There's an even called "input" that if fired whenever the content of the input field changes, for any reason.

```
var select = document.getElementById('select'); // Don't keep looking this up over and over!
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (input.value) {
    select.classList.add('show');
  } else {
    select.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to the event handler is an Event object (it will be always a truthy value). You can get the input length by using `e.target.value.length`.

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if(e.target.value.length !== 0) {
    document.getElementById('select').classList.add('show');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('select').classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

Comment: `e.target.value.trim().length` unless a string of white space is a permitted value.

Answer (score 0):

the class hiddenInput is on the div that wraps the select, not on the select.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="input" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group hiddenInput" id="select-wrapper">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option hidden disabled selected> </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(input){
               if(input.target.value!="") {
                  document.getElementById('select-wrapper').classList.remove('hiddenInput');
             } else {
                  document.getElementById('select-wrapper').classList.add('hiddenInput');
                    }
            });

        </script>
        <style>

           .hiddenInput {
             display: none;
           }


        </style>
```

Comment: that's because I want the entire div to hide/show (including the label)

Comment: I understood that, but the element you added/dropped show class is the select and not the div that wraps it

Comment: and by the way, you don't need that show class, you just need to add/remove hiddenInput class (as the example)

Comment: I agree with your second statement but I don't get what's wrong with hiding the entire div element when I don't want it to be displayed? It's working fine now, as it is.